# BigData: Movies suggestion list for Users, based on Other users Rating for a movie

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-pig

In an interview I was asked a bigdata problem where Dataset with the below schema was given

```
UserId, MovieId, Rating
```

Here each row has Users Rating of Movie data. So based on the movie that user has watched Rating are given (Rating are based on duration of time user has watched, or some other criteria that does not matter).

**Problem statement is to get the top rated MovieId list for each UserId having rating more than 7, which user has not watched yet. Or Basically its a list of movies that can be recommended to a Netflix user.**

So for example for the below dataset

```
User_123    Movie_442   5
User_123    Movie_434   8
User_123    Movie_487   6
User_123    Movie_423   9
User_415    Movie_442   8
User_415    Movie_994   9
User_993    Movie_884   7
User_993    Movie_887   6
User_993    Movie_883   9
```

I am looking for the below output :-

```
User_123    Movie_883
User_123    Movie_994
User_415    Movie_423
User_415    Movie_434
User_415    Movie_883
User_993    Movie_423
User_993    Movie_434
User_993    Movie_442
User_993    Movie_994
```

I have solution for this using `Apache Pig` but I am looking for more optimized approach. Can anyone suggest me a better solution

> LoadFile = load '$input' using PigStorage('\t') as (UserId:
>   chararray, MovieId:chararray, Rating: int);
>       UserIdField = foreach LoadFile generate UserId;
>       DistinctUsers = distinct UserIdField;
>       RatingGreaterThan7 = filter LoadFile by Rating > 7;
>       UsersMovieList = foreach RatingGreaterThan7 generate UserId, MovieId;
>       CrossJoin = cross DistinctUsers, UsersMovieList;
>       FilterMovies = filter CrossJoin by NOT(DistinctUsers::UserId == UsersMovieList::UserId);
>       UsersMovie = foreach FilterMovies generate DistinctUsers::UserId as UserId, UsersMovieList::MovieId as MovieId;
>       FilterAlreadyWatched = JOIN UsersMovie by (UserId, MovieId) LEFT OUTER , LoadFile by (UserId, MovieId);
>       FilterAlreadyWatched1 = FILTER FilterAlreadyWatched by (LoadFile::UserId is null AND LoadFile::MovieId is null);
>       UserMovieWatchList = foreach FilterAlreadyWatched1 generate UsersMovie::UserId, UsersMovie::MovieId;
>       STORE UserMovieWatchList into '$output' using PigStorage('\t');

Answer (score 1):

If its a interview Question , I will try to look at multiple perspective.

1. Find size of all movies having rating > 7.  Say its 200 MB then I will extract this data , write to hdfs.
2. In Pig Job load this data in Reducer memory(After Group By) by using custom UDF to find the for a given user which movies is new to him .

   I may even plan to load the movies above 7 rating in Hbase and do a lookup from Reducer (after groupby)

*Cross Join is not a scalable solution as the rows in the table keep growing.

Comment: Suggestion is good, but its not scalable as you are suggesting to have movies data in memory.

Comment: Nopes only movies whose rating is more than 7. 
A movie 10 Chars.    10 Million movies = 100 MB. which can easily be held in memory. 

You do a prepossessing extract out movies with rating >7 and then either go through in Memory or Hbase (Key Value)